How to write `compose` similar to that in SDF with python?
Recently when I self-learnt MIT 6.5151 course, I first read CS 61AS Unit 0 as the preparation. Then I have read SICP 1 to 2.1 (with related lecture notes) as ps0 requires (also read 2.2.1 as CS 61A notes requires) and then Software Design for Flexibility (SDF) Prologue, chapter 1 and partly Appendix on Scheme. I use MIT-Scheme as the course recommends.
The course problem set 1 has the following problem:

Exercise 2.a: (Not in SDF)
Most modern languages, such as Python and Javascript provide
facilities to write and use combinators like COMPOSE. Pick your
favorite language and write implementations, in your favorite
language, of three of the combinators that that we show in section 2.1
of SDF. Can you deal with multiple arguments? To what extent can you
make them work with multiple returned values? To what extent can you
put in checking for correct arity? Do these requirements conflict.
Demonstrate that your combinators work correctly with a few examples.

My implementation:
import inspect
def compose(f, g):
  g_arity=len(inspect.signature(g).parameters)
  def compose_composition(*arguments):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994347/21294350
    try:
      if len(arguments) != g_arity:
        print("compose Arg number error")
      # print("g return:",g(*arguments))
      
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/691274/21294350
      # very inconvenient.
      g_result=g(*arguments)
      if type(g_result) is list:
        print("g_result",g_result) 
        return f(*g_result)
      else:
        return f(*[g_result])
    except:
      pass
  return compose_composition

assert compose(lambda x:x+2, lambda x:x*x)(2)==2*2+2
print("compose test_2",compose(lambda x:x+2, lambda x:x*x)(2,2)) # this test is expected to throw error.
assert compose(lambda x:["foo",x], lambda x:["bar",x])(2)==["foo",["bar",2]]

The key problem is due to my assumption of passing "multiple returned values" using list. But this will have problems if we just pass one single list, i.e. one type of single-parameter cases. Then we can't differentiate it from "multiple returned values".

The book Scheme implementation solves the above problem by using values which is probably not returned normally as one single data. It is always used as one container of multiple arguments.
(define (compose f g)
  (define (the-composition . args)
    (call-with-values (lambda () (apply g args))
      f))
  (restrict-arity the-composition (get-arity g)))

Is there one way to solve with the above tricky problem using python?

Hinted by the comment, I tried the following where , in (g(*arguments),) is to consider the case that there is only one single object in one tuple.
def compose(f, g):
  g_arity=len(inspect.signature(g).parameters)
  def compose_composition(*arguments):
    try:
      if len(arguments) != g_arity:
        print("compose Arg number error")
      print("g result:",(g(*arguments),),*(g(*arguments),))
      if type(g(*arguments)) is tuple:
        return f(*g(*arguments))
      else:
        return f(*(g(*arguments),))
    except:
      pass
  return compose_composition
compose(lambda x:x, lambda x,y:(x,y))(2,3) # This should throw error
assert compose(lambda x,y:x+y, lambda x,y:(x,y))(2,3)==5

Since python normally use tuple to return multiple values, maybe we just can't differentiate it from returning one single value, i.e. one tuple. So here we assume we should not return one single tuple as one single value.

AFAIK Python doesn't support returning multiple values; it's emulated by returning a tuple, not a list.

@Shawn Thanks for your reply. I haven't learnt python systematically but just learnt it by reading the doc and other tutorials while using it. As https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/# shows, it is ok to use list although it may be not conventional. Both can be unpacked.
